# Can one create a scalable brush in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, brush

Imagine if I'm drawing an image using brushes. Is there by any chance, possible to use the brushes as a vector and resize/transform them, without losing data?

For instance; if you draw a tree in with brushes. Then you want to scale it up by 50%. Is it possible to perform that scaling, without image starting to go blurry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are 2 questions here...

1 : Yes you can create scalable brushes in Photoshop within the "Brush" pallet.

2 : All raster images will blur when scaled to a size bigger than they were created at. If you want to ensure this does not happen you are best to create your image as a vector graphic in an application such as Illustrator.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think the question is about lossless scalable brushes. If so, the only solution I am aware of is to use a Custom Shape (a vector object) instead of a brush.